# Ruby - 'read': can't convert String into Integer

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby, and programming in general.

I am trying to write to a file and then print what I wrote to the file in the terminal.

```
filename = ARGV.first
script = $0

puts "Would you like to read the file?"
puts "If you want to, hit RETURN."
puts "If you don't want to, hit CTRL+C."

prompt = "? "
STDIN.gets

puts "Opening file..."
target = File.open(filename, 'w+')

puts "Reading file..."
puts target.read()

puts "Blank, huh?"

print "Write something: "; line1 = STDIN.gets()
print "A little more: "; line2 = STDIN.gets()

target.write(line1)
target.write(line2)

puts "Let's read it now."
puts target.read()
```

The code runs until I get to the last line, at which time the following error is thrown:

```
exl16_2.rb:26:in `read': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
    from exl16_2.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what this means within the context of what I am trying to do (print out what was written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's causing the error on your side, what Ruby version are you using?  I tried w/1.9 and 2.1 and didn't get that.  There are however issues with your code, try this:

```
filename = ARGV.first
script = $0

puts "Would you like to read the file?"
puts "If you want to, hit RETURN."
puts "If you don't want to, hit CTRL+C."

prompt = "? "
STDIN.gets

puts "Opening file..."
target = File.open(filename, 'w+')

puts "Reading file..."
puts target.read()

puts "Blank, huh?"

print "Write something: "; line1 = STDIN.gets()
print "A little more: "; line2 = STDIN.gets()

target.write(line1)
target.write(line2)
target.rewind()

puts "Let's read it now."
puts target.read()
```

If you read from the file after you wrote it, it will appear empty.  The [`rewind`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-rewind) call will make sure you're reading from the beginning of the file.

Comment: I am running 1.9.3. Rewind worked perfectly, thanks for the help.